# Rails.js data-remote AJAX form appears to submit display:none elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I'm using the standard rails remote => true method to submit a form via ajax. I have a few input text fields in the form that are selectively hidden (via display:none) depending on the circumstance. When those are hidden I would expect (as is the case with a standard form post) that they would not be submitted.

Instead, these fields ARE being submitted with the form somehow. I've combed through the rails.js file here: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js but haven't been able to come up with a reason for why this might be happening.

Is this expected behavior for the ajax data-remote form post approach? If so, I presume I'll need to take a different approach entirely or move those elements out of the form scope completely prior to submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap those in server side if conditions that don't load them to begin with.  Hiding it with css is silly. I could inspect the element in chrome, remove the hidden attribute, and send that field with a bunch of crap.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe I should be more specific: I have a dropdown with 4 "options" and then a 5th "Custom" option which reveals a freeform text box for allowing the user to input their own value. While it's true someone could hack the page to force that to submit, I'll handle validation on the server side. Still, it seems like a bug in Rails.js to be submitting display:none form fields. Standard non-ajax forms don't exhibit this same behavior.